# Using Window Size to Determine Which Function to Use

Tags: javascript, html, css

Wondering if there is a way to do the following:

```
<div onClick="ThingOne()">Button</div>
```

```
function ActionA(){
var Item1 = document.getElementByID("Name1") 
if (Item1.style.opacity == "1") {
      Item1.style.opacity = "0";
    } else {
      Item1.style.opacity = "1";
    }

function ActionB(){
var Item1 = document.getElementByID("Name1") 
if (Item1.style.width == "100%") {
      Item1.style.opacity = "50%";
    } else {
      Item1.style.opacity = "100%";
    }
```

Would like to determine which function to use determined by screen size, if possible?

```
function ThingOne(){
  if ($(window).width() < 470) {
   ActionA();
}
else {
   ActionB();
}}
```

Comment: yes its possible

Comment: @NishargShah Sorry, but I don't know what is meant by "runs in once in load"

Comment: I misunderstand your code so I wrote it but after I edit my comment, you can see my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the working demo.

You misspell `getElementById` function and `onclick` listner.

```js
function ActionA() {
  var Item1 = document.getElementById("Name1")
  if (Item1.style.opacity == "1") {
    Item1.style.opacity = "0";
  } else {
    Item1.style.opacity = "1";
  }
}

function ActionB() {
  var Item1 = document.getElementById("Name1");
  if (Item1.style.width == "100%") {
    Item1.style.opacity = "50%";
  } else {
    Item1.style.opacity = "100%";
  }
}

function ThingOne() {
  if ($(window).width() < 470) {
    ActionA();
  } else {
    ActionB();
  }
}
```

```html
<div onclick="ThingOne()">Button</div>
<div id="Name1">I am Name1</div>
```

Comment: Looks like I had ActionA() and ActionB() in the wrong spots. Thank you so much for clarifying.

Comment: I would but still lack the necessary reputations. Once I achieve that, I will be sure to come back through and upvote those that helped. Thanks again.

Comment: but you can check this answer as the best answer for you by clicking on the right arrow, thanks!